# How do I speed up a custom IHttpHandler for many small thumbnails?

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler

I have a custom IHttpHandler that is trying to process a page with 80-ish thumbnails at once and more are deviled when scrolling the page. (5000 total)

The thumbnails are all 144x144 JPEGs and average 20K each in size.

What kind of settings can I tweak to increase the speed at which it processes the requests? (It can be sluggish when scrolling thru the images)

For what it's worth, we're using classic ASP.NET with the 3.5 framework.

Here is my code so far:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
  string filePath = GetFilePathForContext(context);
  context.Response.Clear();
  context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
  context.Response.WriteFile(filePath, true);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could activate the static Content Caching on the webserver? Or precache the files yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can cheaply process 5000 images and serve them to the browser in realtime. Consider generating the thumbnails upfront and store them in some storage. Later on you will be just serving pregenerated images.

I would suggest that you make sure you return proper content expiry headers so the browser doesn't have to rerequest the same image over and over again.

Consider using a CDN if you want to improve the first load performance and your clients are spread geographically.